# Will low voltage hurt my pi 3 b?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, power

I've bought a Raspberry Pi 3B but at the beginning I used a bad Power Supply Unit that often gave me low voltage warnings.

Now I've a good PSU that never gives me any problems. I've heard that you can get permanent damage like corrupted SD cards from low voltage and I'm wondering: is that true?

If it is, will the damage still last if I change the PSU and reformat my SD card?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange Network - I have taken the liberty of reformatting your question slightly but I hope it is still acceptable to you. I would encourage all newcomers to take the brief [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) which is on a link at the bottom of the page - it may help users to create better questions and get better answers on all SE sites (and you get an extra bronze badge as well! 8-) ) as well as giving pointers on avoiding some of the things that are considered bad etiquette here...

Comment: Filesystem corruption is not physical damage to the card -- although it may be caused by such damage, fs corruption cannot cause it.  It is just scrambled data.  Power issues on the Pi are unlikely to physically damage a card (but nothing is impossible).

Comment: However, as people here will often remind you - don't "pull the plug" without shutting the Operating System down! That is the most common "newbie" mistake and _will_ cause _file_-system corruption...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot envisage a situation where you will have issues after you replace the PSU with a better model unless there was file-system corruption already caused by the previous PSU.

You will probably be fine after performing a `fsck` of all the file-systems on the SD Card as part of a restart {if you were using the previous `init` system I'd suggest a command line `sudo shutdown -F -r` to do a shutdown with an immediate reboot (the `-r` option) and force a file-systems check (the `-F` option) but I do not know if that will work the same on a standard Raspbian Jessie installation now with `systemd` in charge of things...}

Comment: `fsck -y` on boot is enabled by default on current versions of Raspbian; see `/boot/cmdline.txt` and `man kernel-command-line` (and `man systemd-fsck` ;)

Comment: So just to be clear i shouldn't have any problems?

Comment: Try `sudo journalctl | grep "systemd-fsck"` and/or `sudo grep "systemd-fsck" /var/log/syslog`; this should show the results of the last check.  They may be dated `Dec 31 1969` because of the pi's (non-existent) clock but will still appear in chronological order.  You can also add `fsck.mode=force` to `/boot/cmdline.txt` to force a check, and reboot (then remove that).  Make sure `cmdline.txt` remains **all one line** with just spaces between the different key/value pairs.

Comment: _"So just to be clear, I shouldn't have any problems?"_ We hope not - at least not on PSU issues. Any issues you might of had would probably be cleared up on rebooting... if not, let us know! 8-)